# How to add List of Object to Firestore?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a model called `customStep` and I want to push List of customStep called `customSteps` to firestore.

Here's the code for that:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('customSteps')
    .add({'customSteps': customSteps});
```

customSteps collection has documents and those documents consist customSteps field to store an array of customStep. However, this code pushes empty array to the firestore. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does customSteps is an List of objects ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To push an object to Firestore you need to convert your object to map, add this function to your class:

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'yourField1': yourValue1,
      'yourField2': yourValue1,
    };
  }
```

To push a List of customSteps you need to convert all objects to map, you can do it with following method:

```
  static List<Map> ConvertCustomStepsToMap({List<CustomStep> customSteps}) {
    List<Map> steps = [];
    customSteps.forEach((CustomStep customStep) {
      Map step = customStep.toMap();
      steps.add(step);
    });
    return steps;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an Array of map, like picture below.
This map will be your "Object".

So, in your model, you need to declare:

```
class Model {
   ArrayList<CheckList> checklist = null
}


class CheckList implements Serializable {
        String item = null,
        boolean isChecked = false
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Firebase you can't save custom model inside a `Document`

What you can actually do is create a `CustomStep` and a `CustomSteps` Collection.

Inside your `CustomSteps Document` you can create an `array` of `Reference` which is actually a path to your different `CustomStep` Document.

[image: Example of a collection]

This implies of getting the id each time you create a `CustomStep` on firestore and use it as a reference to.

Hope it helps !!